# How to approve swapExactTokensForETH from UniSwapRouter V2, before invoking it?

Tags: web3js, metamask, uniswap

I am trying to create a simple DAI/ETH swapper which lets me swap some DAI for ETH using Uniswap Router V2. I am creating it using React and uniswapSDK. So far, I have managed to connect to my Metamask wallet, get the ABI for the Uniswap contract so I can invoke the method.

However, I am finding it difficult to understand how do I approve this method before calling it? I understand that sending a transaction over the chain needs to first signed, then be called. I am not sure 'how' to approve it? This is my code till now for swapping

```
export const makeSwap = async (
  contract: any,
  account: any,
  library: any,
  amount: any
) => {
  const DAI: Token = await Fetcher.fetchTokenData(chainId, DAItokenAddress);
  const pair: Pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(DAI, WETH[chainId]);
  const route: Route = new Route([pair], DAI);
  const trade = new Trade(
    route,
    new TokenAmount(DAI, library.utils.toWei(amount)),
    TradeType.EXACT_INPUT
  );

  const slippageTolerance = new Percent("50", "10000"); //0.5%
  const amountOutMin = ethers.BigNumber.from(
    trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw.toString()
  ).toHexString();
  const path = [DAI.address, WETH[chainId].address];
  const to = account;
  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 1;
  const value = ethers.BigNumber.from(
    trade.inputAmount.raw.toString()
  ).toHexString();
  await contract.methods.approve(value, account);
  const tx = await contract.methods
    .swapExactTokensForETH(value, amountOutMin, path, to, deadline)
    .call();


   //Fails above this line


  console.log(`Transaction hash: ${tx.hash}`);
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
  console.log(`Transaction was mined in block ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
};
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `.call()` is used when you need to read data from the contract. As you need to send a transaction so use `.send()` instead for `.swapExactTokensForETH`.

For this to work, you need to approve the Uniswap Router to send DAI from our account.

```
await daiContract.methods.approve(UniswapRouterAddress, tokenAmount).send();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and clalrification. I changed my code according to your recommendation, now it says `The method eth_signTransaction does not exist/is not available`. I am connected to an Infura node so I assume this is because I can't expose my private key to it. Do you know what other ways are there? I tried using `web3.eth.signTransaction` and it replied with the same thing :/ If you could help me out, I would be really grateful. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: Changing the provider has let me sign it. So next step would be calling `swapExactTokensForETH` right? Is there anything I need to send along with the transaction?

Comment: Your clarification about `send()` vs `call()` cleared a lot of things. Finally got it to work and successfully sent a few transactions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the DAI contract with approve(UniRouterAddress, amount) not sure about the syntax since im not familiar at all with web3.js but i think you can figure it out ( if this helps understanding better in solidity that would be `IERC20(DAIContractAddress).approve(UniRouterAddress, amount)` )

Comment: So I see the DAI approve takes an `account` and a `uint256 wad` which I assume is the amount. I have send the UniRouterAddress and amount, it returns `true`. After that I tried to invoke the UniRouterAddress but it fails saying `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`. There was no metamask pop up to approve it or anything

Comment: There should have been one. Note that the approval ans the actual swap are 2 different transactions

Comment: So I am making two instances of two contracts to get their methods, `uniContract` and `daiContract`, and calling it like this `await daiContract.methods.approve(UNISWAP_TOKEN_ADDRESS, value).call();`

Both contracts were initiated from the same Web3 instance. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. When I tried to call approve on etherscan for the DAI approve method metamask did pop up asking  for approval